# OAuth: Why is the Implicit grant type called implicit?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

Can someone explain to me why the implicit flow (grant type) of OAuth 2.0 is called "implicit"?

Comment: upvoted because I believe this is a relevant question as it directly relates to the foundation of OAuth 2.0 as a protocol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.2) says this:

> In the implicit flow, instead of issuing the client an authorization code, the client is issued an access token directly (as the result of the resource owner authorization). **The grant type is implicit, as no intermediate credentials (such as an authorization code) are issued**.

Comment: I still don't get it. Implicit means indirect. Why is it called indirect when it's actually quite the opposite?

Comment: Maybe because the client app is indirectly authenticated via the redirect uri

Comment: I think that implicit means that the client's identity is assumed as real one implicitly. This grant is  flawed and deemed insecure. I think the Authorization Code grant also involves some codes that the client and the Authorization server exchange with each other in order to identify themselves before client getting the code and then the token See here https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics-09#page-5